# XAML Autosize CaptureElement in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps

I have the following XAML code in a windows store app:

```
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="capturePreviewCanvas" Width="774" Margin="288,48,0,0" Height="688">
        <CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreviewCaptureElement" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
    </Canvas>
```

I have the `CaptureElement`'s width and height set to autosize and I expected it to fill the entirety of the parent `Canvas` but that doesn't appear to be how it works. If I set the size to `Auto` it simply fills the same size area, even if that area is larger than the parent `Canvas` (which I didn't think was possible).

Example: Canvas is 500x500, Autosize `CaptureElement` sizes itself to around 600x600, exceeding the bounds of its parent `Canvas`.

Why does this happen and how do I get the `CaptureElement` to always autosize to `Fit` or `Fill` its parent `Canvas`?

Comment: [Stretch items to fill canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13621341/95573)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that not all WPF `Panel`s have the ability to alter the size of their children automatically. You can find out which `Panel`s can and can't resize their children in the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) page on MSDN, but in short, `StackPanel`s, `WrapPanel`s and `Canvas`s do *not* resize their children automatically while `Grid`s and `DockPanel`s can.

However, when using a `Panel` that cannot automatically resize its children, there is a trick that you can employ. You can simply data bind the dimensions of your `CaptureElement` to those of the parent `Canvas`:

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreviewCaptureElement" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=capturePreviewCaptureElement}"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=capturePreviewCaptureElement}" />
```

Of course, if you set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties to non zero values, then this will in fact make the `CaptureElement` even larger than the parent `Canvas`.