# Anchor a TextBox to the right and Left (so it’s stretched when parent is resized)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app

I’m looking for the XAML equivalent of Winforms’ `Anchor` property.
I want to anchor a `TextBox` that’s on a `Canvas` (on a UWP app) to the left and right so it’s always 260 from the left and 10 from the right. I’ve tried *many* things, but the one that looks most promising was:

```
<TextBox Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"  Margin="260,10,10,10"/>
```

It does not, however anchor to the right.

Comment: Could you add more context to your XAML? The definition of enclosing container?

Comment: @Steve Nothing special - A Grid with Margin 0. on it a Canvas with Margin 10 (and a background color). And on that - the TextBox. I made sure to remove all else so it doesn't interfere. And, yes, I ran the program, not just trusted the designer. When I resize the Window - the Canvas is resized, but the TextBox not.

Comment: Here your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621041/stretch-items-to-fill-canvas

Comment: @Steve Thanks. But how would I change `Width="{Binding ActualWidth , ElementName=Canvas1}"` to binding to the `Width - 270`? (Perhaps an elementary question, but I'm just beginning with XAML. I tried simply adding the `- 270` but that didn't work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a **3-column** `Grid`.

```
<Grid x:Name="YourOuterGrid">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm accepting this (and you definitely deserve the rep for your answer to the other question and comment!) but I'll note that setting the `Margin`s is usually the solution here, except that I didn't know that `Canvas` is special in that it ignores them.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Normally you just need to set the `Margin` but I thought you wanted a parent container to wrap it hence the answer. :)