# Is there a way to make a off center grid with Windows 10 UA

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make my first Windows UA app, and I'm having a little trouble with the grids.

I'm trying to make half of the screen on the left side a map, and the right side split in 2 boxes. Is this possible? If so, how?

Below is the code for the grid layout that I'm using. Notice the left side is split in 2 boxes.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Basically what I am asking is how do I get an object to take multiple grids, or how to do make it where the row grid doesn't go across the entire screen.

Comment: wait, I marked it as a duplicate.